# Symfony2 anon. access attribute on app.user in twig when app.user is null

Tags: symfony, authentication, attributes, twig

When user is not logged app.user is null - i know that.

I've got a section in my twig template that is used to check for notifications.

```
{% if app.user.notificationsNews == 1 %}
<span class="challenge-notify animated rotateIn">!</span>
{% endif %}
```

no user, no notifications, no problem. Except well the user is null and it still wants to access the attribute

> Impossible to access an attribute ("notificationsNews") on a null
>   variable

is there a good way to bypass that? |default doesn't do the trick

I could check that in my controller and return a different template file, I just want to know if there is a way to do this in twig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be good to go with this

```
{% if app.user and app.user.notificationsNews == 1 %}
   <span class="challenge-notify animated rotateIn">!</span>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are as lazy as me, you can use the [`|default`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/default.html) filter:

```
{% if app.user.notificationsNews|default(0) == 1 %}
<span class="challenge-notify animated rotateIn">!</span>
{% endif %}
```

See [fiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/smb16b)